# Audio Recording via SPI, Raspberry PI

Tags: raspberry-pi, spi, flac

I'm looking to create a system that can be controlled by voice and the voice processing is to be done on a raspberry pi.

I already have the software up and running I just however need to integrate it with my hardware. My system is an electret condenser, through an active filter and into an ADC. I then send the digital signal to the pi through SPI. Due to my software on the pi i need the audio to be in FLAC format.

My question, is there a way to encode it straight to FLAC while its being recorded?